# Handling enctype="multipart/form-data" with two input types which are text and file in MERN

Tags: reactjs, forms, express, mern, multer

`The form is working well when the only input is the type file. However when I add the input type text the system will not work as its used to be.

Here is my form:
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTWHk.png)

Here are my routes:
[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCuqW.png)

My controllers:
[controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtsba.png)

`your text`

I tried everything but it is not from what I expected`

Comment: Post your code instead of images and someone will be able to help you. There are a couple of issues. One in your routes and one in your controller.